# Mongodb Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84

Tags: mongodb

I am running mongodb on nginx server on a Linux machine using SSH.
I am running test cases over it with heavy load. It runs fine for sometime and after a random time duration, the mongo db connection breaks, giving me this error in the `/tmp/da.log` file:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: test
Fri May 16 14:04:44 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed
```

Why does this error occur? Is it some disk space limitation of the server?

I know it can be solved by removing mongod.lock file and restarting the mongodb service. But I will not be restarting the service on production server again and again. I need a permanent solution for this.

Comment: First, it doesn't seem like disk space issue. But are you running on x86 or x64 server? There can be several reasons leads to this situation. You'd better check how many connections are there between server and client. Could be found in the /var/log/mongo/mongo.log. You should also check ulimit -a to see the limitations of your server. Please output the results of these commands.

Comment: how are you starting mongod?  and what is in mongod log file when this happens?  btw, 2.0.4 is a very old version!

Comment: the version is 2.4 , im sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks @yaoxing , but i have a simulation script to test this issue.when i run this simltaion script on my localhost, it behaves in the similar manner , but not able to take even a small amount of load and my pc hangs, and when i try to connect to mongodb again , it gives me the same connection issue (like i get on server). This strongly made me feel it might be a disk space issue.
My server is on amazon Ec2 machine , medium instance. do u think if i upgrade it to a higher instance, this should work?

Comment: No I don't think upgrade would help. Can you check which IP are you binding to?  `netstat -pln | grep mongo`

Comment: its the default ip for mongodb 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: @yaoxing ,  its the default ip for mongodb 127.0.0.1:27017